# C# : How to put variable into meta tag

Tags: c#, .net

I have a html file need to refresh every 10 seconds, so I have this line in html :

```
meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="10; url=Default.aspx"
```

In my C# code I have this :

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page<Br>
{
  public static List<String> Active_User_List=
      new List<String>(), User_List_To_Remove;
  public static int Refresh_In_Seconds=10;<Br>
  ..
}
```

How to replace the 10 with the variable "Refresh_In_Seconds" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh"
      content="<%= Refresh_In_Seconds %>; url=Default.aspx" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="<%=Refresh_In_Seconds%>; url=default.aspx" />
```

FYI, that should probably not be a static member.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do inline code hacks, do it right:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private const int _refresh_In_Seconds = 10;

    public override void OnInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlMeta meta = new HtmlMeta();
        meta.Name = "refresh";
        meta.Content = _refresh_In_Seconds + "; url=Default.aspx"; 

        this.Header.Controls.Add(meta);
    }
}
```

Comment: How are inline code hacks? Does that mean ASP.NET MVC is one giant hack?

Comment: Much cleaner than the inline "hacks".

Comment: Not to mention that inline code is not allowed in some situations on webforms.

Comment: Hm, why MVC is ok and webForms is not? Common!, inline code is just much more readable...

Comment: The important thing is that you're not cutting and pasting it between multiple pages.  The method you are using to share functionality between pages determines which answer is best.  I just inherit from a custom Page object, so this answer is better for me.  If you are using a master page setup, the inline code might be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="<%= _Default.Refresh_In_Seconds %>"; url=Default.aspx" />
```