# Old ASP.NET webform has some inline code getting encoded :(

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, inline-code

I've got a ASP.NET webforms site with some inline code on a master page ..

`<meta property="og:title" content="<%=HeadTitle %>"/>`

but it's rendering that line as..

`<meta property="og:title" content="&lt;%=HeadTitle %>" />`

In the codebehind, i have the following ...

`protected string HeadTitle { get; set; }`

Can anyone help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554725/c-how-to-put-variable-into-meta-tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `runat="server"` attribute from the `<head>` tag in the master page.

Answer (score 2):

The approach I prefer is to set the value of the meta in the code behind.

```
protected void myMeta(string myTitle, string myContent)
{
    Page.Title = myTitle;

    if ((Page.Header != null) && (Page.Header.Controls.Count > 0))

    {
        Page.Header.Controls.AddAt(1, new HtmlMeta("content", myContent));

    }
}
```

The .aspx itself would just have the normal tags

```
<head id="myHead" runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's in a `<head>` with `runat="server"`, you can either remove the `runat="server"` part, or you can change `<%=` to `<%#` and call `Header.DataBind();` from within `Page_Load`